# Create Nuget Packge Suppots Dependecy Injection and use Interface to be implemented

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, interface, nuget-package

I am trying to create a weather Nuget package that can be used in any .net
core project, the library should give me the current weather
for a specific city that I chose in Celsius or Fahrenheit.

I will use the weatherapi.com to get the current weather.

The library should support the dependency injection (DI) throw a service called
IGetCurrentWeather with one method that’s take a city name and optional
parameter to chose whether I want the result in Celsius or Fahrenheit.

I should be able to register the library in the startup of any .NET CORE project and
provide the necessary configurations like the Code below

```
builder.Services.AddWeatherApi(WeatherOptions=>
WeatherOptions.ApiKey= "d1398cba8a894feb9f7180821232602");
```

the interface (the apikey below is for example):

```
public interface IGetCurrentWeather
    {
        public async Task<string> GetCurrentWeather()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=d1398cba8a894feb9f7180821232602&q=London&aqi=no\r\n");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseBody;
        }
    }
```

AddWeather Function:

```
public static class WeatherApi
    {
        public static WeatherOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager
        public static IServiceCollection AddWeatherApi(this IServiceCollection services, Action<WeatherOptions> configure)
        {
            services.Configure(configure) ;


            return services;

        }
```

WeatherOptions:

```
public class WeatherOptions
    {
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    }
```

how can i use the ApiKey that i entered in startup.cs when call GetCurrentWeather() function to access weatherapi.com account?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: you could read about the nuget package here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio

Comment: Ok mr.sir thanks for your advice. I will remove it

Comment: @SirRufo have understood the question? Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: Don't put an actual implementation in your interface. Your interface should define the things that any implementing class should have. It shouldn't directly contain implementation on a new design like this. Create a class that implements the interface, then have that class get an instance of WeatherOptions via its constructor (this is called Constructor Injection).

Comment: ok, thats mean : in interface just declare empty function without code inside?

Comment: could you please help me if you have time, its urgent case for me

Comment: @mohammedalani we like buzz words like **urgent** here **not at all**. what makes your question more urgent than all the other open questions here on this site? so please calm down and do not try to spam people. if anybody has an answer or a question you will get notified. if it is really urgent to you, then feel free to find a freelancer (there are some site were you can find them) who will help you in your case.

Comment: @SirRufo ok mr.Rufo , i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted solution here is close. But in general, you should not put an actual implementation in an interface. You can think of an interface as a contract, it defines the operations that you expect any implementing class to be able to perform.

You start off okay with this:

```
builder.Services.AddWeatherApi(WeatherApiOptions =>
    WeatherOptions.ApiKey= "d1398cba8a894feb9f7180821232602");
```

We should rename your interface, just for consistency's sake. And remove the implementation. So what you used to call IGetCurrentWeather should look like this:

```
public interface IWeatherApi
{
    public Task<string> GetCurrentWeather();
}
```

Then you need a class that implements the interface. It should receive the WeatherApiOptions via constructor injection:

```
public class WeatherApi : IWeatherApi
{
    readonly WeatherApiOptions _weatherApiOptions;

    public WeatherApi(IOptions<WeatherApiOptions> weatherApiOptions)
    {
        _weatherApiOptions = weatherApiOptions.Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetCurrentWeather()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={_weatherApiOptions.ApiKey}&q=London&aqi=no\r\n");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }
}
```

Then, an extension method that helps wire up your class with the DI container. Notice that I renamed it to better describe what its purpose is

```
public static class WeatherApiDependencyInjectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddWeatherApi(this IServiceCollection services, Action<WeatherApiOptions> configure)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IWeatherApi, WeatherApi>();
        services.Configure(configure) ;
        return services;
    }
}
```

And rename your options class to make it clearer what its for:

```
public class WeatherApiOptions
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I noticed you're using HttpClient directly. There's [some downfalls associated with that](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). I recommend using [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot mr.mason. I appreciate your help highly. When i done with it . I will contact you on your email to tell you why i need it.

Comment: @mohammedalani You don't need to contact me on email for this. If it works, then great - feel free to mark the answer as accepted. If it doesn't work, then feel free to leave a comment explaining why it doesn't work.